# Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease Cannot initiate the connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

[image]

I tried to run sudo apt update after a long time and looks like some packages are not getting updated due to this error.

How should I resolve this?linux

Answer (score -1):

I just rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list, redo "sudo apt-get update", then everything return to normal.